# Android different size image issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image

I had four background images:

(240*320, 320*480, 480*720, 640*960)

Now the problem is that I had samsung galaxy tab 2 which takes image from hdpi meaning image size will be 480*720 and tab size is 640*1024. Then the image stretches. I am confused in image setting in device please any of you have idea then please help me.

Comment: Post your XML or we cant help you...

Comment: i cannt thing it's requred xml i hade background will fill parent and i had set backgroud bg image and proble is there above

Comment: If you have a background image, you have either defined it in your XML or added in your code - post either of these or we can´t help you.

Answer (score 3):

Create **drawable-sw600dp-hdpi** folder in res and put your file to this folder

**Example**

**deprecated**

1. drawable-hdpi
2. drawable-mdpi
3. drawable-nodpi
4. drawable-xhdpi

**New Technique Configuration examples**

1. **drawable-sw320dp -> 320dp:** a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi,
   320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
2. **drawable-sw480dp -> 480dp:** a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800
   mdpi).
3. **drawable-sw600dp -> 600dp:** a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
4. **drawable-sw720dp -> 720dp:** a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280
   mdpi, etc).

**Provide different layouts for different screen sizes**

The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are **small**, **normal**, **large**, and **xlarge**. For example, layouts for an extra large screen should go in **layout-xlarge/.**

Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the above size groups are **deprecated** and you should instead use the **sw<N>dp** configuration qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your layout resources. For example, if your multi-pane tablet layout requires at least **600dp** of screen width, you should place it in **layout-sw600dp/**.

Using the new techniques for declaring layout resources is discussed further in the section about [Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: you right but for all device how i can set. i want to support all device images

Comment: ohh thats too much image i have to put any other option for this ?

Comment: Please try to understand new Technique for drawable. this is the only way

Comment: @Kiti this all above layout will help in only tab layout if i want to suuport all size device degining then?

Comment: Please see my edited answer you get idea how to support multiscreen using new Technique

Comment: Will new configurations work for applications targeted < 3.2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Kirit is right.

You can use some tricks but this depends on your background image. In our case, we had a logo which was placed on a background with a gradient. what we did in the end: we drawed our gradient on a `RelativeLayout` and placed the logo as a `transparent-png` file above, and defined it as always in the center and the `scaleType` to `fitCenter`.  (If you would use `fitXY`, `ImageView` would be resized)

```
 // layout/view.xml
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/splashscreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_background">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/splashscreen_logo" />
</RelativeLayout>

// drawable/hape_background
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#f1f1f1" android:endColor="#d7d7d7"/>
</shape>
```

Is it possible to add some transparency to your background images corners?!